# geometry node: mesh as curve profile

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, hair, curve-modifier

I'm learning about hair for games, I created some hair cards and to modify them I'm using the curve modifier.
At first everything was fine, but soon the scene was a mess, full of curves and meshes. I wanted to know if there was a way to use hair cards as a curve profile, so I would only have the mesh profiles and the rest would be curves and I could still easily edit the profile and change the curves that use it,and I would have the same UV as the profile.
for comparison purposes, while I was researching this I found the Hair tools addon which has a tool that works as I mentioned(strands filter), but I'm just learning about hair for games and I didn't want to buy an addon for now(after all I don't do this often).
[image: hair card with curve modifier]

Comment: I found a geo node very close to what I really wanted although it still has a defect, I don't know much about geometry nodes but from what I've read the Blender geo nodes system itself still doesn't support changing the curve radius manually (alt+s in edit mode) , but I managed to work around this problem while Blender doesn't add this support

Answer (score 0):

If the profile shape you want to use is a Mesh object, you can convert it to Curve object to be able to choose it, while selecting the other Curve used for the hair strand length, in Properties panel > Objet Data Properties > Bevel > Object.

[image]

But if you really want your profile shape to remain a Mesh object, you can also do this conversion to curve "virtually" within a Geometry Nodes modifier, using the "Mesh to Curve" node:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained it well. I think profile wasn't quite the right word to use, it would be more the idea of instantiating the mesh on the curve and using it as a control. https://youtu.be/vYXeqwqauzE?si=Oh9MQeJkn1gjXGa7 In this video I found something very close to what I wanted, I don't know much about geometry nodes but from what I researched it still doesn't support editing the mesh radius manually, so this is probably the closest I can find